# NetSuite Analytics Dataset filter for last item fulfillment per item

Tags: sql, netsuite, dense-rank

I need to create a dataset that shows the Date of the most recent Item Fulfillment for an item. I need to take the results from this dataset and join to an item dataset to pull various item attributes.

In creating the dataset filter, I am trying to use a dense rank formula but is not validating based on the syntax of the `transactionlines.item` field reference.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY {transactionlines.item} ORDER BY {trandate} DESC)
```

Any ideas of the correct syntax here?

I tried this formula

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY {transactionlines.item} ORDER BY {trandate} DESC)
```

but got this error message

> You have syntax error in your formula (Unsupported element: Element does not exist or element class SqlValue is expected.). Please see the documentation for supported syntax. (Error on line 1 column 33.)